# How to properly format list of Countries (XPath) into columns in the Console app?

Tags: c#, xpath

Currently the list is being printed to the console with a while loop and using tabs for spacing. However some of them aren't lining up properly and I'm not sure why. Here is my current code:

```
    // Prints a numbered list of countries.
    XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
    XPathNodeIterator nodeIt = nav.Select("//@name");
    int num = 1;
    int numCountries = 1;
    while (nodeIt.MoveNext())
    {
        if (num % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\t\t\t" + numCountries + $". {nodeIt.Current.Value}");
            num++;
        }
        else if (num % 3 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write("\t\t\t" + numCountries + $". {nodeIt.Current.Value}");
            Console.WriteLine();
            num = 1;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("\t" + numCountries + $". {nodeIt.Current.Value}");
            num++;
        }
        numCountries++;
    }
```

And here is an image of how it is looking currently:
[image: List of Countries]

Any tips on going about how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You will need to measure and pad with spaces for columns, tab will not work over a certain length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make this a little easier for your self and a tad more extensible with some extension methods.

**Given**

```
public static class Extensions
{
   public static IEnumerable<string> AsEnumerable(this XPathNodeIterator iterator)
   {
      while (iterator.MoveNext())
         yield return iterator.Current.Value;
   }

   public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Chunk<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, int chunkSize)
   {
      return source
         .Select((x, i) => (Index : i, Value : x))
         .GroupBy(x => x.Index / chunkSize)
         .Select(x => x.Select(v => v.Value).ToList());
   }
}
```

**Usage**

```
XPathNavigator nav = doc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator nodeIt = nav.Select("//@name");

var rows = nodeIt
   // Convert to IEnumerable
   .AsEnumerable() 
   // Add prefixes, PadRight is the maximum column width
   .Select((x, i) => $"{i + 1}. {x}".PadRight(20)) 
   // Chunk into columns
   .Chunk(3)
   // Concat into rows
   .Select(x => string.Concat(x));

// Write it to the console
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, rows));
```

<sub>Note : This is untested, however it should give you a potential solution.</sub>

You could also measure the max length for each column, and pad accordingly, however it's a little more complicated.